# how to evaulate: $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+x^5)}{(e^{x^3}-1)\sin(x^2)} $

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

How do I evaluate: $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+x^5)}{(e^{x^3}-1)\sin(x^2)} $ ?

according to Taylor's series, I did like this:

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+x^5)}{(e^{x^3}-1)\sin(x^2)}=\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x^5 - \frac{x^{10}}{2}+ O_3(x)}{(x^3+ \frac{x^6}{2!} +O_4(x))(x^2- \frac{x^6}{3!} +\frac{x^{10}}{5!} +O_4(x))} $$

but how do I continue from here?

Comment: What is $O_3(x)$? Is that $O(x^{15})$?

Comment: Looks like both numerator and denominator begin with $x^5$.

Comment: @kobe yes. I just write it that way.

Comment: Well, if you make up notation, you aren't likely to communicate well with people.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I will apply new things that I learn here. I didn't say that it was true what I wrote.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: divide both the numerator and the denominator by $x^5$.

Answer (score 1):

We have

\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^5 - \frac{x^{10}}{2} + O(x^{15})}{(x^3 + \frac{x^6}{2!} + O(x^9))(x^2 - \frac{x^6}{3!} + O(x^{10}))}\\
&= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1 + O(x^5)}{(1 + O(x^3))(1 + O(x))}\\\\
&= \frac{1}{(1)(1)}\\
&= 1.
\end{align}

Comment: shouldn't it be $O(x^{15})$  in the numerator of second line?

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani no, because the second line was obtained from the first by multiplying $\frac{1/x^5}{1/x^5}$. The numerator obtained after that is $1 - \frac{x^5}{2} + O(x^{10})$, which is $1 + O(x^5)$.

Answer (score 1):

From Taylor's expansions at $x=0$, $\log(1+x^5) \approx x^5$, $e^{x^3}-1 \approx x^3$ and $\sin x^2 \approx x^2$, as $x \rightarrow 0$. Thus,

$$\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\log(1+x^5)}{(e^{x^3}-1)(\sin x^2 )} = \lim \limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^5}{x^{3} x^{2}} =1.$$